# Complex numbers problem

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I have to solve [image]

where n is equal to n=80996.

Comment: The answer you will get is very very large are you sure that this question is correct?

Comment: @Alizter The answer is not very large because $|\sqrt3+5i|^2=28=|4+2\sqrt3i|^2$, so $|(\sqrt3+5i)/(4+2\sqrt3i)|=1$.

Answer (score 4):

Using $\displaystyle  a^nb^n=(ab)^n\text{ and }\frac {a^n}{b^n}=\left(\frac ab\right)^n$ where $a,b$  are complex numbers and $n\ne0$ in case of division

$$\text{and }\displaystyle\frac{x+iy}{p+iq}=\frac{(x+iy)(p-iq)}{(p+iq)(p-iq)}=\frac{xp+yq+i(py-xq)}{p^2+q^2},$$

$$\frac{(\sqrt3+5i)^n}{(4+2\sqrt3i)^n}=\frac{(\sqrt3+5i)^n}{2^n(2+\sqrt3i)^n}=\frac1{2^n}
\left(\frac{\sqrt3+5i}{2+\sqrt3i}\right)^n$$

$$=\frac1{2^n}\left(\frac{(\sqrt3+5i)(2-\sqrt3i)}{(2+\sqrt3i)(2-\sqrt3i)}\right)^n=\left(\frac72\right)^n\left(\frac{\sqrt3+i}{7}\right)^n=\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac i2\right)^n$$

$$=\left(\cos\frac\pi6+i\sin\frac\pi6\right)^n$$

Now use [de Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula)

Comment: I think there is a mistake somewhere [look here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+%28sqrt%283%29%2B5i%29%5En%2F%284%2B2sqrt%283%29i%29%5En+equal+to+7%5En%28cos+%28pi%2F6%29+%2B+i+sin+%28pi%2F6%29%29%5En)

Comment: Almost right! But $(2 + \sqrt 3i)(2 - \sqrt 3i)$ equals 7, not 1. So the result is even simpler.

Comment: @TonyK, thanks for all your support. Rectified

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram Alpha [confirms](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sqrt%283%29%2b5i%29%5E6/%284%2b2sqrt%283%29i%29%5E6) that

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt3+5i}{4+2\sqrt 3i}\right)^6 = -1$$

You can take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sqrt3+5i}{4+2\sqrt3i}=\frac{\sqrt3+5i}{4+2\sqrt3i}\cdot\frac{4-2\sqrt3i}{4-2\sqrt3i}=\frac{14\sqrt3+14i}{28}=\frac{\sqrt3+i}2=\cos\frac{\pi}6+i\sin\frac{\pi}6;$$$$\left(\frac{\sqrt3+5i}{4+2\sqrt3i}\right)^n=\left(\cos\frac{\pi}6+i\sin\frac{\pi}6\right)^n.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt3+5i}{4+2\sqrt 3i}\right)^n=\left(\frac{14\sqrt3+14i}{28}\right)^n=(\sqrt3/2+(1/2)i)^n=$$
$$=\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{6}+\sin\frac{\pi}{6}i\right)^n=\cos\frac{n\pi}{6}+\sin\frac{n\pi}{6}i$$